# How to load com.android.music code into Eclipse and compile?

Tags: android, eclipse

I did a [git on the com.android.music](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git) app and then created a project in eclipse from existing code.  I chose 2.1 as the sdk target but I am getting errors trying to compile.

Is the music app referencing code that is not part of the 2.1 sdk?  Can someone list the steps for how to compile in eclipse?

`Description Resource Path Location Type
ArrayListCursor cannot be resolved to a type PlaylistBrowserActivity.java Music/src/com/android/music line 529 Java Problem
MediaFile cannot be resolved AlbumBrowserActivity.java`

Answer (score 1):

> Is the music app referencing code that
>   is not part of the 2.1 sdk?

Absolutely. Most of the built-in apps for Android were created before there was an SDK. You will not be able to build them in isolation from the rest of the firmware without substantial work. Work which, BTW, would be welcome contributions back to the Android open source project, if you were so inclined... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the applications manifest file. It will contain an attribute stating which version of the SDK the application was built with.