# How to reference R.java of other apps in Android, like com.android.music?

Tags: android, reference

I am trying to develop an app to supplement the built-in music player.  I've used git to download the com.android.music package and looked around at its code.  I can launch the music player by copying some of its code and launching activities with intents.

Now what I need to do is get a handle to its current view.  In the MusicUtils.java file, I see a line that says

```
View nowPlayingView = a.findViewById(R.id.nowplaying);
```

I'd like to do the same thing.  Only I don't have access to the `R.java` file, so I can't write e.g. `R.id.nowplaying`.  How do I do this?  How do I reference the music players R.java?  I do know the R.java stuff is declared public so that shouldn't be a problem.  Right?

Is it even possible?  I saw this related question and am now wondering: [How to load com.android.music code into Eclipse and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437271/how-to-load-com-android-music-code-into-eclipse-and-compile)

Btw, I'm working against the Android 2.2 SDK, but it'd be helpful to know if the answer is different for older versions such as 1.5.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get a handle on a `View` that is not in your process, even if you have access to the `R` class.

Answer (score 1):

The R class is code generated by the Android plateform from the XML's resources files found in the /res directory of the project. It means you want to use the git repo where you got the MusicUtils.java and go to the root dir of the related project to look out in `/res/layout/`. You then have to find an XML layout file declaring the View having the id "nowplaying".

Copy this file into your own project 'res/layout' directory, and Android will compile a R class for you to access the R.id.nowplaying you miss so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have the source code, so take the resources and build your own R file.  Also, you can access android system resources by `android.R.<type>.<name>` as well.